# Зависит ли планировщик cron от перезагрузки системы

Tags: linux, crontab

Как я понял Crontab зависит от системного времени (что логично)

Например с такой задачей:

`*/10 * * * * /script.sh` - запуск скрипта каждые 10 минут

Если сделаю перезагрузку когда до cron задачи осталось некоторое кол-во времени и загружу систему соответственно до наступления времени задачи значит ли это то, что Cron выполнит эту задачу по планируемому расписанию, или при перезагрузке <<таймер>> задачи обнулиться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Крон работает довольно просто:

- демон смотрит время каждую минуту
- если совпадает с выражением, то выполняет

Таким образом, если начало перезагрузки 09:59:59 а система поднялась в 10:00:03, крон задачу НЕ выполнит.

> cron then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking each command to see if it should be run in the current minute

из `man cron`

### Как это можно проверить

Создадим расписание с логом на каждую минуту, и перезагрузим систему несколько раз за минуту. А затем посмотрим по логу время выполнения.

Я использовал Докер, но можно сделать и на реальном сервере.

Файл `crontab.txt` пишет текущее время в лог:

```
* * * * * date | tee -a /var/tmp/cron.log
```

Файл `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine

ADD ./crontab.txt /tmp/crontab.txt
RUN crontab /tmp/crontab.txt

CMD crond && sleep 6000
```

```
# билдим
docker build . -t cron-test
# запускаем
docker run -d --name cron-test-container cron-test
# смотрим, что упало в лог:
docker exec cron-test-container sh -c "cat /var/tmp/cron.log"
# перезапускаем контейнер
docker restart cron-test-container
# ... и снова смотрим лог
```

Мой лог:

```
Sat Jan 11 03:20:00 UTC 2020
Sat Jan 11 03:21:00 UTC 2020
Sat Jan 11 03:22:00 UTC 2020
```

Таким образом, крон не запускал задачи после перезагрузки, которые должны были выполнится в эту минуту.

Чтобы привязатся к перезагрузке, есть специалное выражение `@reboot`. Подробности в `man 5 crontab`. А также есть [anacron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron)

Comment: Я не совсем понял, получается как я понял в случае выполнения с определенной периодичностью например раз в 30 минут оно выполяет задачу когда число минут делится на 30 и получается целое чило, вроде 30/30 = 1, 60/30 = 2 и др, при этом у случае создания задачи выполняемой с периодичностью 30 мин в 27 минут она впервые выполнится не через 30 минут,  а в 30 минут (через 3 минуты)

Comment: @RedWoolf, все верно. Привязка к системному времени.

Comment: На `systemd` есть Timers вполне гибкий вариант олдскульноуму `cron` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers